# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <every package> , No matching distribution

Tags: windows, pip, scikit-image, requirements

On windows, I can't install any packages of these : numpy, matplotlib, skimage,...

My python version is 2.7

Everytime the same error :

**Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-image (from ver
sions: )
No matching distribution found for scikit-image**

I have tried to consider 'abce' requirements, but didn't work.

Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: What is Python version? `python --version`?

Comment: check out [this unofficial link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image). Here the `whl` files for various python versions for Windows are available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using pip to install your packages ?

First install numpy : `pip install numpy`

Then install matplotlib `pip install matplotlib`

Then install scipy `pip install scipy`

And finally install skimage `pip install scikit-image`

The error you obtain means that you're not giving the right name for your package

Hope it helps

Cheers